# deleting rows from an excel file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am opening an excel file like this:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

string str;
int rCnt = 0;
int cCnt = 0;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("csharp.net-informations.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

I would like to know:
**How do I loop through all the rows and delete every row in which the string `SomeString` does not appear in `column A`?**

I know how to loop through every value:

```
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
{
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
    {
        str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2;
        MessageBox.Show(str);
    }
}
```

But I do not know how to delete the entire row

Comment: You should be able to use: 'range.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XLDirection.xlUp)' - just set the range with the worksheet object (xlWorksheet).

Comment: @PatrickPitre thanks so much! how do i set the range?

Comment: It would look like: range = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "B1"); range.EntireRow.Delete(Excel.XLDirection.xlUp);

Comment: What library is being used? What usings?

Answer (score 15):

Once you have a reference to the worksheet say

```
for(int i = 1; i <=100; i++)
{
  if(!worksheet.Cells[i,1].Contains("SomeString"))
  {
     ((Range)worksheet.Rows[i]).Delete(shiftDirection)
  }
}
```

where shiftDirection see here: [Range.Delete method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.delete.aspx)

You may have to cast the Cell's content to a string.

Answer (score -1):

I know the question has been already answered, but you can try something like below

```
 for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
         if (!dt.Rows[i]["column A"].Contains("SomeString "))
         {
             dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
         }
     }
```