# How to delete a row from excel on button click in C#

Tags: c#, excel, row

How can I delete a row from excel sheet based on product id provided in textbox1. Using that product_id it should delete the whole row from excel sheet & display updated data in datagridview?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951188/deleting-rows-from-an-excel-file-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

if you'll look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.delete.aspx) you'll find explanation on how to delete using `Range.Delete` Method. this method is for deleting from exel and as Karthik posted you can do

```
 ((Range)worksheet.Rows[i]).Delete(shiftDirection)
```

for your code in order do delete data from row i.
the `shiftDirection` is optional and Specifies how to shift cells to replace deleted cells.

Comment: Keep up the good work, we do read. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


         {


        OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        string excelDelete = "DELETE FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE ID = '" + dgvExcelList["ID", dgvExcelList.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString() + "'";//modify as your need
        OleDbCommand Deletecmd = new OleDbCommand(excelDelete, myConn);
        myConn.Open();
        Deletecmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConn.Close();
        /*code to update datagridview*/



    }
```

Comment: In this what is dgvExcelList ????

Comment: name of excel sheet...