# Removing empty rows in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, null, delete-row

I want to remove **empty rows** at the end of program exection. In details I am inserting some results after calculation using **C#** in predefined excel sheets. At the end I need to delete/remove the empty rows programatically. Could any one suggest solution. My code is little big so I am unable to include here. For your understanding I am giving some input and output view of excel. In below Output Excel the rows **D** and **E** having empty row I want to remove programatically without mentioning the range.

Input Excel /Pre defined Excel Files

```
A   1   2   3   4
B
C
D
E
```

output Excel

```
A   1   2   3   4
B   ABc cde nAC 123
C   cdf fed x2  123
D
E
```

Comment: You havent even mentioned what library you use to create your excel file.

Comment: I am just inserting a data to predefined template excel and also I using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference for importing excel.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951188/deleting-rows-from-an-excel-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: can you knows the row's num of input in runtime?

Comment: I don't know the row number, only need to find the empty rows programmatically.

Comment: @Nachiappan R excel sheet rows are around 1,048,576 rows in excel 2013 (Which initially are empty). you can do what you want but its a very overwhelming execution (1,048,576 times iteration!). but if your  predefined excel sheet has limited row numbers, its more logical to do that. its easy to get row number of D (in your example) but if i did not misunderstand, row number of E is not clear, so the last row number is 1,048,576!  if i misunderstand your need, correct me.

Comment: Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49232456/1114531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a Range Object. I assume here that you are using Excel interop.

Let say you have your book open, then set the range then delete it It should look something like this

```
ApplicationClass excel = new ApplicationClass();
//...

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range cel = (Range)excel.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex];
cel.Delete();
```

You can also try using:

```
for(int i = 1; i <=20; i++)
{
   excelRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1];
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(excelRange.Text.ToString()))
   {
       ((Range)excelWorkSheet.Rows[i]).Delete(excelRange);
   }
}
```

Check out the link below

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/469fdf10-35cc-46b2-a875-7b974deb5659/how-to-delete-all-empty-rows-from-a-excel-sheet-using-microsoftofficeinteropexcel?forum=exceldev

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952004/4373895
Here "Something" is your null value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: While including (Range)excel.Cells[rowIndex, columnIndex]; I am facing error, could you help me on this. and in second solution I need to find null value or somestring. Are you trying to say somestring as null?

Comment: I tried the social msdn, but when i am trying this below lines I am getting this error "No overload for method 'CountA' takes '1' arguments"
 if (application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(exlwooksheet.Rows[i]) == 0)
                (exlwooksheet.Rows[i] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Delete();

Comment: VikrantMore Can you look and help me on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove empty rows in Excel file using the following code

```
 xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet sheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];
 var LastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
 LastRow = LastRow + sheet.UsedRange.Row - 1;
 for (int i = 1; i <= LastRow; i++)
 {
   if (application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sheet.Rows[i]) == 0)
       (sheet.Rows[i] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Delete();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code works perfectly and creates a new blank row for a specified row and column number :

```
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet1.Cells[RowNumber, ColumnNumber];
                            Excel.Range Row1 = rng.EntireRow;
                            Row1.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods that deletes empty rows and columns from an Excel worksheet.

```
/// <summary>
/// Deletes empty rows and columns from the end of the given worksheet
/// </summary>
public static void Trim(this Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    worksheet.TrimColumns();
    worksheet.TrimRows();
}

/// <summary>
/// Deletes empty rows from the end of the given worksheet
/// </summary>
public static void TrimRows(this Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
    while(worksheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(range.Rows[range.Rows.Count]) == 0)
        (range.Rows[range.Rows.Count] as Excel.Range).Delete();
}

/// <summary>
/// Deletes empty columns from the end of the given worksheet
/// </summary>
public static void TrimColumns(this Excel.Worksheet worksheet)
{
    Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
    while(worksheet.Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(range.Columns[range.Columns.Count]) == 0)
        (range.Columns[range.Columns.Count] as Excel.Range).Delete();
}
```